# Cannot find DisplayTemplates for common datatypes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I was following [this](https://youtu.be/XSbQ_5TSSiM?t=4340) YouTube tutorial for MVC and I had some doubts regarding the EditorFor and LabelFor HTMLHelpers and looked it up online. Found [this](http://cpratt.co/displaytemplates-and-editortemplates-for-fun-and-profit/) blog which explains in detail. However, in the blog, the mentions that we need to have the [datatype].cshtml file in our Views\Shared folder for us to be able to apply the EditorFor/LabelFor methods to the properties of datatype [datatype]. But in my project, I don't see any String.cshtml file anywhere in the solution. So how come I am able to use the EditorFor method for AccountNumber property which is of datatype String. Sample code below

Shouldn't I be having the String.cshtml file in Views\Shared folder to use these EditorFor methods?

```
 <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AccountNumber, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AccountNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AccountNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Because the source code include default [DisplayTemplates](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/Html/DefaultDisplayTemplates.cs) and [EditorTemplates](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/Html/DefaultEditorTemplates.cs) for use by the `DisplayFor()` and `EditorFor()` methods

Answer (score 0):

As [Stephen Muecke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3559349/stephen-muecke) mentioned in the comments, there are default templates in the `System.Web.Mvc.Html` namespace. I think the comment really says it all, but I'll try to clarify what's going on behind the scenes. If you check the source code for [`EditorFor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.editorextensions.editorfor(v=vs.118).aspx) you will eventually end up at the `internal static` `TemplateHelpers`, which contain dictionaries for some default types, which in turn use `DefaultEditorTemplates`. These are used until you actually override them yourself by placing a view inside the folders `Shared/EditorTemplates` or `Shared/DisplayTemplates`. So, even if `Boolean` is in the dictionary of the default templates, you may override it by placing `Boolean.cshtml` in the on of the folders.

From `TemplateHelpers`:

```
private static readonly Dictionary<string, Func<HtmlHelper, string>> _defaultEditorActions = new Dictionary<string, Func<HtmlHelper, string>>((IEqualityComparer<string>) StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) {
  { "HiddenInput", new Func<HtmlHelper, string>(DefaultEditorTemplates.HiddenInputTemplate) },
  { "MultilineText", new Func<HtmlHelper, string>(DefaultEditorTemplates.MultilineTextTemplate) },
  { "Password", new Func<HtmlHelper, string>(DefaultEditorTemplates.PasswordTemplate) },
  { "Text", new Func<HtmlHelper, string>(DefaultEditorTemplates.StringTemplate) },
  { "Collection", new Func<HtmlHelper, string>(DefaultEditorTemplates.CollectionTemplate) },
  { "PhoneNumber", new Func<HtmlHelper, string>(DefaultEditorTemplates.PhoneNumberInputTemplate) },
  { "Url", new Func<HtmlHelper, string>(DefaultEditorTemplates.UrlInputTemplate) },
  { "EmailAddress", new Func<HtmlHelper, string>(DefaultEditorTemplates.EmailAddressInputTemplate) },
  { "DateTime", new Func<HtmlHelper, string>(DefaultEditorTemplates.DateTimeInputTemplate) },
  { "DateTime-local", new Func<HtmlHelper, string>(DefaultEditorTemplates.DateTimeLocalInputTemplate) },
  { "Date", new Func<HtmlHelper, string>(DefaultEditorTemplates.DateInputTemplate) },
  { "Time", new Func<HtmlHelper, string>(DefaultEditorTemplates.TimeInputTemplate) },
  { typeof (Color).Name, new Func<HtmlHelper, string>(DefaultEditorTemplates.ColorInputTemplate) },
  { typeof (byte).Name, new Func<HtmlHelper, string>(DefaultEditorTemplates.NumberInputTemplate) },
  { typeof (sbyte).Name, new Func<HtmlHelper, string>(DefaultEditorTemplates.NumberInputTemplate) },
  { typeof (int).Name, new Func<HtmlHelper, string>(DefaultEditorTemplates.NumberInputTemplate) },
  { typeof (uint).Name, new Func<HtmlHelper, string>(DefaultEditorTemplates.NumberInputTemplate) },
  { typeof (long).Name, new Func<HtmlHelper, string>(DefaultEditorTemplates.NumberInputTemplate) },
  { typeof (ulong).Name, new Func<HtmlHelper, string>(DefaultEditorTemplates.NumberInputTemplate) },
  { typeof (bool).Name, new Func<HtmlHelper, string>(DefaultEditorTemplates.BooleanTemplate) },
  { typeof (Decimal).Name, new Func<HtmlHelper, string>(DefaultEditorTemplates.DecimalTemplate) },
  { typeof (string).Name, new Func<HtmlHelper, string>(DefaultEditorTemplates.StringTemplate) },
  { typeof (object).Name, new Func<HtmlHelper, string>(DefaultEditorTemplates.ObjectTemplate) }
};
```

From `DefaultEditorTemplates` for creating a `Boolean`:

```
internal static string BooleanTemplate(HtmlHelper html)
{
  bool? nullable1 = new bool?();
  if (html.ViewContext.ViewData.Model != null)
    nullable1 = new bool?(Convert.ToBoolean(html.ViewContext.ViewData.Model, (IFormatProvider) CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
  if (html.ViewContext.ViewData.ModelMetadata.IsNullableValueType)
    return DefaultEditorTemplates.BooleanTemplateDropDownList(html, nullable1);
  HtmlHelper html1 = html;
  bool? nullable2 = nullable1;
  int num = nullable2.HasValue ? (nullable2.GetValueOrDefault() ? 1 : 0) : 0;
  return DefaultEditorTemplates.BooleanTemplateCheckbox(html1, num != 0);
}

private static string BooleanTemplateCheckbox(HtmlHelper html, bool value)
{
  return InputExtensions.CheckBox(html, string.Empty, value, DefaultEditorTemplates.CreateHtmlAttributes(html, "check-box", (string) null)).ToHtmlString();
}

private static string BooleanTemplateDropDownList(HtmlHelper html, bool? value)
{
  return SelectExtensions.DropDownList(html, string.Empty, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>) DefaultEditorTemplates.TriStateValues(value), DefaultEditorTemplates.CreateHtmlAttributes(html, "list-box tri-state", (string) null)).ToHtmlString();
}
```

Here's the source code from Core:

https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures/ViewFeatures/TemplateRenderer.cs

Comment: Let's say I had to use a different behavior for a String field in one form and I choose to override the template for datatype String i.e. String.cshtml. So all the other places where I have string property in view files would also be  affected? Looks like I am missing something really simple as that will not be the case. How do I cater to a special case scenario where I just have to have an exception in displaying a commonly used datatype ?

Comment: @karun10 - That's a another question, but yes it will be used everywhere. But there are ways around it. First, you can pass parameters into it as such - [EditorFor() and html properties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625327/editorfor-and-html-properties). Or if you really want something for only one situation you can use a [partial view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13934671/using-partial-views-in-asp-net-mvc-4) instead of `EditorFor`.